# Git - mark files as unmerged

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have following situation:

I have something like main branch in my project(green color in the picture).

My workmate has create his own branch (red color) and pushed his commit.

Unfortunately before one of the pushes he **merged** his red branch with green branch **discarding all changes** which i had pushed in the meantime (R2 on the picture). After that he made some another pushes (R3 and R4).

Currently, i am in G2 and i want to merge my green branch with red branch, but unfortunately all **changes between G1 and G2 are skipped** when i merge this two branches because git sees this changes as merged.

So my question is how to mark my changes beetween G1 and G2 as unmerged with red branch or at least how to see **all differences** between this two branches to be able to merge manually?? Nice to see another proposals.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps revert the Bad commit?

Comment: Will it "unmerge" files or only delete changes added between R1 and R2?

Comment: Its not clear what you want out of this. You can't unmerge. It's not a thing. so forget about that and concentrate on what you can do to achive whatever it is you want the outcome to be. I think, though the question really isn't clear, your going to have to cherry pick G1 and G2 onto the end of the red branch. What exactly is a "bad merge" anyway?

Comment: What the "bad merge" is? (explanation) 
My workmate was in R1 -> he merged with my green branch discarding all my changes -> he added his own changes -> he commited and pushed

Comment: and you've told him how stupid his actions are I'm hoping?! So there's nothing bad about the merge. As far as GIT is concerned it's just a merge. To undo it would require re-writing the history, which is not an easy task. If it we're me I'd create a new branch at R1 (or G1 or even G2) and cheery pick each commit into it again and merge as you see it. Then discard both the red and Green branches

Comment: I can say it was an accident - he pressed Ctrl+t in webstorm by mistake (it's a shortcut for update), after update he decided to revert project to form before update using webstorm local history and pushed everything to repo...

Comment: Thing is, if you colleague had realise his mistake at R2 then this would all be a lot easier to solve. There's a moral there somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

"mark as unmerged"? That, you won't be able to do moving forward. If you are willing to go the best possible way (correct history) I would say you checkout R1 and merge G2 *correctly* (or the other way around, it would be the same output). Then you could cherry-pick R2..R4 and then you have a nice new history with the right merge. If you don't want to overwrite history, you might checkout G2 and `git merge --no-commit R4` so that you have a chance to get your stuff back before committing.